# How to edit html of an element through a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In AngularJS, How can I get access to the actual html of an element that a directive attribute sits on. I'm not interested in editing it's attributes, I want to actually manipulate the html itself. Change the element to a span, or even change it to a comment.

For example:

```
<div my-directive>
    <h1>hey</h1>
</div>
```

I want to change to:

```
<span my-directive>
    <h1>hey</h1>
</span>
```

Or even to:

```
<!-- div my-directive -->
    <h1>hey</h1>
<!--/div -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/YWfSF/3/

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    compile: function(elem) {
        elem.replaceWith('<span>' + elem.html() + '</span>');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't completly work since other directives that sit at the same level still do things... `<div my-other-directive my-directive><h1>hey</h1></div>` results in undesired behaviour..

Answer (score 0):

here is a really simple example. Depending on your need you have to extend it a bit.

```
app.directive('mydirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    template: '<span my-directive><h1>hey</h1></span>',
    replace:false,
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude){
      console.log('tElement',tElement);
      console.log('tAttrs',tAttrs);
      console.log('transclude',transclude);
    }
  }
});
```

i know, it's generalized, but your question is too ;)
have fun!

EDIT: [forgot plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/esY2TjGRC5BGRFwJ1wmC?p=preview)